# Stucking with nested grouping in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to implement a nested group query in mongodb and I'm getting stuck.

My collection documents look like this.

```
[
    {
        '_id': ObjectId('6171377e78671af1ae78f35a'),
        'state': 'SA',
        'term': 1,
        'year': '2021',
        'dateRange': [
            '2019/01/29',
            '2019/04/12',
        ],
    },
    {
        '_id': ObjectId('6171377e78671af1ae78f35a'),
        'state': 'SA',
        'term': 2,
        'year': '2021',
        'dateRange': [
            '2019/01/29',
            '2019/04/12',
        ],
    },
    {
        '_id': ObjectId('6171377e78671af1ae78f35b'),
        'state': 'SA',
        'term': 1,
        'year': '2022',
        'dateRange': [
            '2019/04/29',
            '2019/07/05',
        ],
    },
    {
        '_id': ObjectId('6171377e78671af1ae78f35b'),
        'state': 'TAS',
        'term': 1,
        'year': '2021',
        'dateRange': [
            '2019/04/29',
            '2019/07/05',
        ],
    },
];
```

I'm trying to achieve a list of term-dates as follow (group term dates by year wise in each state) but don't have idea how to achieve this.

```
[
    {
        state: 'SA',
        termdates: [
            {
                year: '2021',
                data: [
                    {
                        term: 1,
                        dateRange: [
                            '2019/01/29',
                            '2019/04/12',
                        ],
                    },
                    {
                        term: 2,
                        dateRange: [
                            '2019/01/29',
                            '2019/04/12',
                        ],
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                year: '2022',
                data: [
                    {
                        term: 1,
                        dateRange: [
                            '2019/01/29',
                            '2019/04/12',
                        ],
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        state: 'TAS',
        termdates: [
            {
                year: '2021',
                data: [
                    {
                        term: 1,
                        dateRange: [
                            '2019/01/29',
                            '2019/04/12',
                        ],
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
];
```

Can you guys please help me with this. How can i achieve this result.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Why do you have empty array `termdates: []` for `state: 'TAS'`? Storing date/time values as string is a design flaw, store **always** proper `Date` objects.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is first `$group` by `year x state` so you can build the "nested" `data` field.
Then `$group` again just by `state` to create the final structure, like so:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        state: "$state",
        year: "$year",
        
      },
      data: {
        $push: {
          term: "$term",
          dateRange: "$dateRange"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.state",
      termdates: {
        $push: {
          year: "$_id.year",
          data: "$data"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VqypRWFpUo-)

Comment: Thank you Tom Slabbaert, It's working as expected. Thank you so much!!